# Como limitar a quantidade de linhas em um ListBox em Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Estou estudando sobre Tkinter e me deparei com um problema quando quis limitar a quantidade de resultados que apareciam em uma Listbox. Procurei na internet, mas não achei nada a respeito.

Estou desenvolvendo um "Chat", onde o que eu preciso é que somente 10 últimas linhas (mensagens) apareçam na ListBox, cujo tamanho será delimitado para suportar as 10 linhas sem que haja o rolamento. Os resultados que estiverem fora dessa limitação deverão ser ocultados.

Estou usando o Python 3.8.1.

Desde já agradeço.

Segue código completo abaixo:

```
from tkinter import *

class App():
    def __init__ (self, master = None):

        self.fonte_padrao = ("Arial", "12")

        self.frame = Frame(master).pack()        

        self.entry_nome = Entry(master, font = self.fonte_padrao)
        self.entry_nome.place(x = 0, y = 0, width = 300, height = 30)
        self.nome = None

        self.btn_cadastro = Button(master, text = "Entrar", command = self.entrar)
        self.btn_cadastro.place(x = 310, y = 0, width = 90, height = 30)

        self.lista_msg = Listbox(master, font = self.fonte_padrao)
        self.lista_msg.place(x = 10, y = 50, width = 380, height = 190)

        self.entry_txt = Text(master)
        self.entry_txt.bind("<Return>", self.btn_focus)
        self.entry_txt.place(x = 10, y = 250, width = 380, height = 65)

        self.btn = Button(master, text = "Enviar")
        self.btn.bind("<Return>", self.enviar_msg)
        self.btn.bind("<Button-1>", self.enviar_msg)
        self.btn.place(x = 175, y = 320, width = 50)

    def entrar(self):
        self.nome = self.entry_nome.get()
        self.entry_nome.destroy()
        self.btn_cadastro.destroy()
        self.lbl_nome = Label(self.frame, text = self.nome, font = self.fonte_padrao)
        self.lbl_nome.place(x = 0, y = 0, width = 400)

    def btn_focus(self, event):
        self.btn.focus()

    def enviar_msg(self, event):
        txt = self.entry_txt.get('0.0', END)        
        msg = self.nome + " - " + txt

        self.entry_txt.delete('0.0', END)
        self.entry_txt.focus()

        self.lista_msg.insert(END, msg)

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x350")
root.title("Chat")
App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara se você precisa que sempre que o usuário digite algo e o listbox acompanhe o último item você pode utilizar o método see do listbox

```
def enviar_msg(self, event):
    txt = self.entry_txt.get('0.0', END)        
    msg = self.nome + " - " + txt

    self.entry_txt.delete('0.0', END)
    self.entry_txt.focus()

    self.lista_msg.insert(END, msg)
    # O método see faz com que o listbox mostre o index desejado
    # passar o size da lista faz com que ele mostre o último item
    self.lista_msg.see(self.lista_msg.size())
```

porém é possível ainda ver a conversa usando o roll do mouse
caso você queria só mostrar as 10 mensagens e impedir o usúario de ver as outras, uma opção é você deletar o primeiro item da lista e adicionar um novo ou desativar o event trigger do roll do mouse

para fazer a opção de remover o primeiro item é bem simples

```
    # verifica se a lista possui 10 itens
    if self.lista_msg.size() >= 10:
        # caso tiver, remove o primeiro item da lista
        self.lista_msg.delete(0)
    self.lista_msg.insert(END, msg)
```

é bem difícil achar material do tkinter, eu recomendo o site do elfbot ou do tutorialspoint

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_gui_programming.htm

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda!